# Messed non-ASCII characters in PDF form filled up with pdfbox library

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am filling up a PDF form using library `pdfbox` 1.8.10. Unfortunately if there is a non ASCII text, the whole text gets scrambled. But it is okay when using `itext` library. But I need to stick with pdfbox...

How to make `pdfbox` processing unicode correctly?

See comparison:

[image: pdfbox vs itext]

That strange "by" prefix is always the same.

Some files:

- [Original PDF form](https://www.dropbox.com/s/02c26ps2udhere9/by-acrobat.pdf?dl=0) created with Apache Acrobat DC
- [PDF produced by itext](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnwhnw7iyi1gdua/by-acrobat.pdf.itext.pdf?dl=0)
- [PDF produced by pdfbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ksauaneyuvs990q/by-acrobat.pdf.pdfbox.pdf?dl=0)

Code snippets used are simple:

```
// pdfbox
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
PDField field = acroForm.getField("name1");
field.setValue("hello жмкул!");

// itext
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inPdfFile);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outPdfFile));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.setField("name1", "hello жмкул!");
```

Comment: Try the same with 2.0 RC2. 1.8.10 doesn't support non-ascii.

Comment: Just tried it. App failed with `IllegalArgumentException: U+0436 is not available in this font's Encoding`. I don't know how to solve that yet, especially in the case when I do not load any custom font, just using one pre-existent in PDF.

Comment: Then it's more tricky... either wait here, or as on the user mailing list.